# Find parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can an ancestor (a "parent" element some levels above) of a clicked element be found?

The element is not a direct parent but it is further up in the DOM tree.

In the example below i need to find `<a id='collapser1'>` if `<a id='collapser4'>` is clicked. How to do that?

```html
<ul id="pdfbutton">
  <li>
    <a id="collapser1" href="#collapser1" 
       class="jqcNode" style="cursor: pointer;">Link 1
    </a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
      <li>
        <a id="collapser2" href="#collapser2" 
           class="jqcNode" style="cursor: pointer;">Link 2
        </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="collapser3" href="#collapser3" 
           class="jqcNode" style="cursor: pointer;">Link 3
        </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="collapser4" href="#collapser4" 
           class="jqcNode" style="cursor: pointer;">Link 4
        </a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Regarding terminology: You are looking for a particular *ancestor* of the clicked node.

Comment: A quick introduction into the family tree. An element is either a sibling, ancestor or descendant of another. A immediate ancestor is commonly called the **parent**, and an immediate descendant is a **child**.

Comment: Update: Actually it is not an ancestor. It is a child of an ancestor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the `ul` ancestor, then to it's `li` ancestor, then into the `a` tag:

```
$(this).closest('ul').closest('li').children('a')
```

Comment: See my comment at @Tatu's answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Of course, I didn't consider that the other lists are also children.

Answer (score 0):

First find the parent ul and then the parent li of that

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
$(element).parent() returns the immediate parent.



 $("#collapser3").click(function() {   
      var parentElement = $(this).parent();
    });
```

this will may helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: That will select an LI element.